# using old tfstate for terraform destroy purposes

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created the aws beanstalk resources using terraform and included **S3** as the backend for the storage of the **tfstate**. I'm reusing the same terraform infra code to deploy same resources with different properties like different instance-type, security groups, etc...

My question:, is there a way where I can still destroy the previous beanstalk infra created by same terraform code? Maybe referring to the tfstate files created from s3 then do the terraform destroy? thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Terraform S3 backend configured in your codebase containing the Terraform state with the resources you would like to destroy, you can run `terraform destroy` and see the removal plan.

You can also simply run `terraform apply` and Terraform will converge the previously existing infrastructure to the newly desired one, without the intermediate `destroy` run